# BSoD with 0xc00000e9

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

SuperUser Members

I get a BSoD error in my Window 10 (Bad System Config Info) for that solution I reboot my PC and get into Diagnostic but here still a problem (Repairing Disk Error), so I take Windows DVD to avoid this error but in DVD boot I get this error "An Expected I/O error" with error 0xc00000e9

How Can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a hard drive failing so you'll probably want to replace that. You can run diagnostics on it with a vendors tool or some brand-name PC's have a key on boot that'll boot into diagnostics. I/O is Input/Output error so in theory that could ALSO be a bad DVD disc or DVD drive, but based on your wording its less likely to be them. Process of elimination would have you try replacing each piece to find the cause/culprit